# What are some interesting starter games for a very young child?

Tags: recommendations, kids

I'm interested in playing some games with our very young (16 months) son.

I think he's a little young for most things yet - I'm familiar with Old Maid, Dominoes, and similar games that involve a little bit of matching; those seem like they will be good points of entry for him shortly.  Marbles, while also great, involves tiny pieces that can be swallowed.

I want to avoid games like Candyland and probably even Chutes and Ladders - they annoy me.  :-)  Other games with a lot of cards or paper products involved are probably right out - they'll get slobbered on or destroyed.  Small parts get eaten.

What are some concrete, not commonly known games that might be interesting to him?

Comment: Hey Elijah, sorry I've closed your question.  Recommendation questions are not a good fit for a Q/A site and we have banned them.  These questions tend to devolve into long lists with no real way to vote on the answers which interacts poorly with our reputation system.  I hope you understand and stick around.

Comment: That "other site" that focuses on lists of games has several on this topic.  You can try http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/33475/first-games-my-picks-for-kids-younger-than-three or try searching GeekLists for things like "Toddler".

Comment: My son likes Hi Ho Cherry-o

Answer (score 4):

I was going to say CandyLand and Chutes and Ladders, because as annoying as they are they are still a huge hit with my 4 year old. I am hoping that she will soon be old enough for Catan Junior! She already wants to play Catan with Mama.